# Use Css in a php/html doc

Tags: php, html, css

I have a website that I've been working on recently that I'm having a particularly difficult struggle with. I don't really know how to code much aside from a python class a few years ago and the open-source script that I've been working off of is primarily css, php and html.

I added a tab to the homepage with the help of someone who works on the script, but I'm stuck now trying to make this tab (an about us section) look nice. I know enough (and know how to look up) css to be able to make it look the way I want it to, but I can't seem to get my css style sheet to link to the php code.

```
    <?php
// set the root path
define( "MDSROOT", dirname( __FILE__ ) );

// include the config file
include_once( MDSROOT . "/config.php" );

// include the header
include_once( MDSROOT . "/html/header.php" );

?>



<p>We believe in helping people.</p>

Other text


  <p>   <!-- stats iframe -->
                <div class="status_center">
                    <iframe width="150" height="50" frameborder=0 marginwidth=0 marginheight=0 VSPACE=0 HSPACE=0 SCROLLING=no  src="display_stats.php?BID=1" allowtransparency="true"></iframe> </p>

<?php
include_once( MDSROOT . "/html/footer.php" );
?>
```

My css style sheet is named "aboutus.css" and the code I copied here is "aboutus.php" How do I get these to link?

Comment: Hey, take a look at this https://cssnewbie.com/using-css-with-php-tutorial/#.WwMZZXWFNZI

Comment: Can you show us your `header.php`? That most likely contains your `<head>` tag, inside which you should put a `<link>` relative to your CSS.

Comment: As noted below by Glenn, you need to include a link to the stylesheet in your header.  Then those styles will apply to every page that calls the header.  Also, you have a div tag inside a p tag.  By w3 spec, you should not do that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
place style.css file in html folder.

in top of header page add:

```
 <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="html/styles.css">
 </head>
```

include header on each php page.